# Can I write Assert message in my log file?

Tags: c#, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, assert

I have Assert smt like `Assert.AreEqual(2, 3, "wrong")`

Can I write `wrong` in my log file without needing to use `Log.log.Error("wroong");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `TestContext` class like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    private readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("your_logger");

    [Test]
    public void Demo()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, 3, "wrong");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.FailCount > 0)
            logger.Error(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message);
    }
}
```

This will write a full error message to your log file:

> wrong
>   Expected: 2
>   But was:  3